# Can I use VBA in Access to determine if a user has multiple instances of a database open?

Tags: vba, ms-access-2016

I am looking for a way to determine if a user current has multiple instances of an Access database open on their machine. The purpose of this check would be to ensure better session handling.

It is perfectly fine for a user to open multiple instances. There are some elements of our work where this is a necessity, to browse existing records while entering a new one.

I came across [this old forum post](https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/list-all-open-databases.250418/) where a function is given to output a list of the currently open databases in the Workspace. I thought I may be able to adapt this to determine if the same database is open more than once on their machine. However, in testing the function (removing the part that opens a separate database), it always outputs the name of our database twice, regardless of whether I have just one instance open, or two or three.

Here's the adapted code I am using:

```
Public Sub listDBs()
    
    Dim wrkCurrentWorkSpace As Workspace
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strDatabases As String
    
    Set wrkCurrentWorkSpace = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)

    For i = 0 To wrkCurrentWorkSpace.Databases.Count - 1
       If (i = 0) Then
         strDatabases = wrkCurrentWorkSpace.Databases(i).Name
       Else
         strDatabases = strDatabases & Chr$(13) & Chr$(10) & wrkCurrentWorkSpace.Databases(i).Name
       End If
    Next
    
    MsgBox strDatabases
    
    Set wrkCurrentWorkSpace = Nothing

End Sub
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Your code is fine, the issue is not with your VBA code.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Any idea what the actual issue is?

Comment: The issue may be related to your office installation not being up to date or corrupted, OR the way you open the access database, OR your DDE settings OR other access plugins. Sorry I can't help you more. My current setup does not allow for the database to opened twice, so you need to provide information about your setup and how you open your database(s), in order for people to help you.

Comment: Btw I am using Office 2019.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'm not sure what info to provide, so I'll look for another way to handle this.

Comment: Are the databases opened in the same workspace? On my computer each database opens on its own Access instance and the count is always (1 + number of linked databases).

Comment: Good question! Is it possible to force a database to open in a specific workspace, without actually launching it from within another database?